# Sorting One list alphabetically and having the other 3 list be re sorted in the same order

Tags: c#, list, sorting

```
List<string> listOfStudentsNames = new List<string>();
List<string> listOfStudentsHomeTown = new List<string>();
List<string> listOfStudentsFavoriteFood = new List<string>();
List<string> listOfStudentsFavoriteColor = new List<string>();
```

So in the mini app the user enters the students name, followed by hometown, favorite food, and favorite color. So my goal at any time once the user adds a new student the names in the list are put in alphabetical order. Which that I can get to work just fine I know how to get the list in alphabetical order. My issue is I need to get the other 3 list hometown, favorite food, and color to be resorted according to how the name list was sorted (aka so the students names still re align to what their hometown favorite food and color is). I'm having trouble coming up with the logic to do this..

This is how I have the sorting list alphabetically function set up.

Right now it's only sorting the names with the issue being how i sort the other three lists to how names was sorted alphabetically

```
public static void SortListAlphabetically
        (List<string> listOfstudentsNames,
        List<string> listOfStudentsFavoriteFoods,
        List<string> listOfStudentsHomeTown,
        List<string> listOfStudentsFavoriteColor)
    {
        List<string> unSortedList = new List<string>(listOfstudentsNames);
        List<string> tempListOfStudentsFood = new List<string>(listOfStudentsFavoriteFoods);
        List<string> tempListHomeTown = new List<string>(listOfStudentsHomeTown);
        List<string> tempListFavColor = new List<string>(listOfStudentsFavoriteColor);

        unSortedList.Sort();

        for (int i = 0; i < unSortedList.Count; i++)
        {
            listOfstudentsNames[i] = unSortedList[i];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why using four separate lists instead of only one list of e.g. tuples?

Comment: Why use four separate lists instead of one `List<Student>`?

Comment: Its a home work question so the required the information be stored in list. @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp can i some how store favorite foods, hometown, and favorite color in the list?

Answer (score 0):

This may solve your question. I don't know if you are adding the names and you wanna keep order or if you have already the names and you wanna sort all at the end keeping the match between the name index and the other info index. I code the two variants:

Way 1 (Adding the names keeping order):

I made a BinaryInsert method that inserts the name in the correct position using binary search (this is very fast) and then it returns the position it inserted the name. This will be the position where you most insert the other info.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AddStudent("Mike", "home1", "food1", "color1");
            AddStudent("Pete", "home2", "food2", "color2");
            AddStudent("Andrea", "home3", "food3", "color3");
            AddStudent("Zoey", "home4", "food4", "color4");
            AddStudent("Tom", "home5", "food5", "color5");
        }

        static List<string> listOfStudentsNames = new List<string>();
        static List<string> listOfStudentsHomeTown = new List<string>();
        static List<string> listOfStudentsFavoriteFood = new List<string>();
        static List<string> listOfStudentsFavoriteColor = new List<string>();

        public static void AddStudent(string name, string homeTown, string favFood, string favColor)
        {
            int namePos = BinaryInsert(listOfStudentsNames, name);
            listOfStudentsHomeTown.Insert(namePos, homeTown);
            listOfStudentsFavoriteFood.Insert(namePos, favFood);
            listOfStudentsFavoriteColor.Insert(namePos, favColor);
        }

        public static int BinaryInsert<T>(List<T> elements, T item) where T : IComparable
        {
            return BinaryInsertRescursive(elements, item, 0, elements.Count);
        }

        private static int BinaryInsertRescursive<T>(List<T> elements, T item, int startIndex, int finishIndex) where T : IComparable
        {
            if (startIndex == finishIndex)
            {
                elements.Insert(startIndex, item);
                return startIndex;
            }

            int pos = startIndex + (finishIndex - startIndex) / 2;

            if (item.CompareTo(elements[pos]) <= 0)
                finishIndex = pos;
            else
                startIndex = pos + 1;

            return BinaryInsertRescursive(elements, item, startIndex, finishIndex);
        }
```

Way 2 (Sorting all at the end and keep the match between names index and other info index):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Assuming these are the names that where added with their info
            listOfStudentsNames = new List<string>() { "Tom", "Andrea", "Zoey", "Mike", "Pete" };
            listOfStudentsHomeTown = new List<string>() { "home1", "home2", "home3", "home4", "home5" };
            listOfStudentsFavoriteFood = new List<string>() { "food1", "food2", "food3", "food4", "food5" };
            listOfStudentsFavoriteColor = new List<string>() { "color1", "color2", "color3", "color4", "color5" };
            Sort(listOfStudentsNames, 
                listOfStudentsHomeTown, 
                listOfStudentsFavoriteFood, 
                listOfStudentsFavoriteColor);
        }

        static List<string> listOfStudentsNames = new List<string>();
        static List<string> listOfStudentsHomeTown = new List<string>();
        static List<string> listOfStudentsFavoriteFood = new List<string>();
        static List<string> listOfStudentsFavoriteColor = new List<string>();

        public static void Sort(List<string> names, params List<string>[] otherInfo)
        {
            // I use params for the other info because you will be able 
            // to add more info-lists without making any changes to this code

            // save the index of each name
            var nameWithIndexes = names.Select(x => new Tuple<string, int>(x, names.IndexOf(x))).ToList();

            //sort the list by the names
            nameWithIndexes.Sort((x, y) => x.Item1.CompareTo(y.Item1));

            names.Clear();
            names.AddRange(nameWithIndexes.Select(x => x.Item1));

            // get de index of the names afert sorting
            var order = nameWithIndexes.Select(x => x.Item2);

            // sort the other info by the index order int the variable "order"
            for (int i = 0; i < otherInfo.Length; i++)
            {
                var newOrder = new List<string>();
                foreach (var index in order)
                {
                    newOrder.Add(otherInfo[i][index]);
                }
                otherInfo[i].Clear();
                otherInfo[i].AddRange(newOrder);
            }               
        }
```

I hope this could help.